# Django & Ajax - "Like" button, how to make it work for mutliple posts on a page?

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, ajax

There are a lot of similar questions already raised, but so far haven't managed to fix my setup. I successfully created a 'like' button with a counter, but it works only on one post, where there are multiple on one page (while hitting the like button on another post, only the first one gets changed).

What should I change in the code, to make it work for all posts?

HTML button

```
{% for news in newss %}
<div class="col-md-6">
                    
{% csrf_token %}
<button class="like-button" value="{{ news.id }}" > Like </button>
<span class="" id="like_count">{{ news.news_likes_count }}</span>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

AJAX

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.like-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "like" %}',
      data: {
        newsid: $('.like-button').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        action: 'post'
      },
      success: function (json) {
        document.getElementById("like_count").innerHTML = json['result']
      },
      error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {

      }
    });
  })

</script>
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def like(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        result = ''
        id = int(request.POST.get('newsid'))
        news = get_object_or_404(News, id=id)
        if news.news_likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            news.news_likes.remove(request.user)
            news.news_likes_count -= 1
            result = news.news_likes_count
            news.save()
        else:
            news.news_likes.add(request.user)
            news.news_likes_count += 1
            result = news.news_likes_count
            news.save()

        return JsonResponse({'result': result,})
```

urls.py

```
path('like/', views.like, name='like')
```

models.py

```
class News(models.Model):
    news_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    news_text = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    news_author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    news_created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    news_likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='n_like', default=None, blank=True)
    news_likes_count = models.BigIntegerField(default='0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the value of the *clicked* button, so:

```
data: {
    newsid: $(this).val(),
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
    action: 'post'
},
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You do not have to store the number of items of a `ManyToManyField` in another field. You can use [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) when you need to determine this by the database. Storing this explicitly in a field is a form of *data duplication*, and it turns out that keeping these in sync is harder than what one might expect.

Comment: Thanks @Willem, that worked + details from the manual on: https://michealscode.medium.com/django-ajax-like-and-upvote-button-on-listview-solved-in-5-simple-steps-96dbdc39daca